# How do I get a smooth finish on heavily weathered wood?

Tags: sanding

I have a cedar porch swing that has been left to the elements for many years and is heavily weathered where the wood has grooves along the grain pattern. I'd like to restore this to a smooth finish, but not having much luck.

I've tried down to 40 grit sandpaper with a power sander and it still doesn't seem to get it smooth enough to start working my way up the grits. I'm guessing it just takes a lot of time and elbow grease, but I feel like I'm getting diminishing returns.

Any tips short of disassembling it and running it through the planer?

Comment: You already know the basic methodology that has to be employed, short of disassembly and sending it through the planer or hand planing it (which TBH could be worth it, depending on the construction details). Sanding this sort of surface is just one of those things that takes as long as it takes. Although power sanding of course saves a ton of sweat equity it still takes plenty of time and effort. But then even regular sanding does :-) *"it still doesn't seem to get it smooth enough to start working my way up the grits"* What's the issue exactly? A picture could be worth a thousand words here.

Comment: What kind of a power sander are we talking about here? If you have a light touch and some courage, a belt sander might be your friend.

Comment: Oscillating sander and hand sanding. Just feels like no matter how long I sand there are still striations in the wood.

Comment: Striations? Are you having difficulty in evening out the earlywood and latewood?

Comment: I 2nd, Pictures please!

Answer (score 1):

You could apply layers of polyurethane until you've got a nice smooth surface. This is the same stuff they apply to bar tops to it will be very long wearing.

Simply apply thin layers until all the grooves are filled, then apply another couple of coats to ensure that highest points are sufficiently protected.

Comment: Um, I have some notes! 1. Semi-exterior application, so poly isn't appropriate (the wood got this weathered for a reason). 2. It's not the same stuff they apply to bar tops #notevenclose 3. We really can't know what kind of varnish coverage would be sufficient to fill the texture until photos are provided, as asked. 4. They may not want to use a film finish for the project, for any one of the key reasons (or all of them).